# Stop Host server from using Ethernet interface assigned for guest VM?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kvm

i have as erver (proliant DL380 gen9). it has 4 ethernet ports eno1 thru eno4.
i am using ubuntu 17.10 and KVM with 4 multiple guest vm.
On the host, i have setup virbr0 on eno1.

Everything worked fine until i did my update from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10.
After that update, i can access all the guest vms properly but my DHCP server (Meraki) keeps sending me warnings of IP conflict.
If i lookup the MAC addresses of the machines requesting the same IP i find out they are those of eno1-4. 
but i left these unassigned specifically so i can use them for my guest VMs.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto virbr0
iface virbr0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eno1
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0   
#hwaddress ether 30:e1:71:5c:ec:60
```

Here is my cldsrvr.xml define

```
> ...  <interface type='direct'>
>       <mac address='52:54:00:92:c2:cc'/>
>       <source dev='eno3' mode='private'/>
>       <model type='virtio'/>
>       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
>     </interface> ...
```

If you notice in my xml define of the VM, i changed the mac address from 30:e1:71:5c:ec:61 to the 52:45:....

So my conclusion was that somehow the host server is still using the interfaces eno2-4 when it is not supposed to.

is there a way to stop the Host server from using Ethernet interface assigned fro guest VM?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is simple.

In /etc/network/interfaces, declare the Ethernet interfaces as "manual".
This way host will not attempt to get an IP address for them, and they stay available for the guest VMs to use. e.g.

```
...
# Ethernet port for cad-srvr VM
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

# Ethernet port for nxtcld-srvr VM
auto eno3
iface eno3 inet manual
...
```